# Can't see EXTRA_PROCESS_TEXT on android app - React Native+Java

Tags: javascript, java, android, react-native

I made an app that sending strings with a text selection pop-up menu from outside the app to the app. But the string doesn't show up in the opened app over chrome. When I open the actual application in the background, I can see the string there. What do I need to do to make the selected word appear in the application opened over chrome?

Video: https://vimeo.com/manage/videos/589440077

App.js

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { Text, View, DeviceEventEmitter } from 'react-native';


const App = () => {

  const [text, setText] = useState('')

  // get selected text from native
  useEffect(() => {
    DeviceEventEmitter.addListener("EventReminder", (data) => {
      console.log(data.eventProperty)
      setText(data.eventProperty)
    });
  }, [])


  return (
    <View style={{ justifyContent: "center", alignItems: "center" }}>
      <Text selectable>
        TRANSLATION
      </Text>
      <View style={{width:200, height:30, borderWidth:2, marginTop:50, justifyContent:'center', alignItems:'center'}}>
        <Text>{text}</Text>
      </View>
    </View>
  )
}

export default App;
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```js
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.translationapp">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
      android:name=".MainApplication"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
      android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
      android:allowBackup="false"
      android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
      <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize|uiMode"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        
        <!-- add app name to the text selection pop up menu -->
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PROCESS_TEXT" />
            <data android:mimeType="text/plain"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>        
      
      </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

MainActivity.java

```js
package com.translationapp;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.annotation.RequiresApi;

import com.facebook.react.ReactActivity;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.Arguments;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactContext;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.WritableMap;
import com.facebook.react.modules.core.DeviceEventManagerModule;

import java.util.Objects;

public class MainActivity extends ReactActivity {

  /**
   * Returns the name of the main component registered from JavaScript. This is used to schedule
   * rendering of the component.
   */
  @Override
  protected String getMainComponentName() {
    return "translationApp";
  }

  // send events to JS ---------------------------------
  @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(null);
    if (getIntent().getAction() != null && getIntent().getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_PROCESS_TEXT) != null) {
      String text = Objects.requireNonNull(getIntent().getCharSequenceExtra(Intent.EXTRA_PROCESS_TEXT)).toString();

      WritableMap params = Arguments.createMap();
      params.putString("eventProperty", text);

      sendEvent(Objects.requireNonNull(getReactInstanceManager().getCurrentReactContext()),
              params);
    }
  }
  private void sendEvent(ReactContext reactContext, @Nullable WritableMap params) {
    reactContext
            .getJSModule(DeviceEventManagerModule.RCTDeviceEventEmitter.class)
            .emit("EventReminder", params);
  }
}
```

Comment: Funny that you posted this today as I've just started researching this topic. One thing of note, DeviceEventEmitter has been deprecated and there's a comment in this blob: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/1490ab12ef156bf3201882eeabfcac18a1210352/Libraries/EventEmitter/RCTNativeAppEventEmitter.js#L15